# Deploying OpenCms on Tomcat via Puppet Slave SSH on AWS - Getting HTTP 404 Error

Tags: tomcat, opencms

I'm trying to deploy OpenCms on Tomcat, which is deployed on my Puppet Slave SSH on an AWS instance running Ubuntu. I've deployed Tomcat using the manager app, but when I try to access OpenCms via the endpoint :8080/opencms/, I'm encountering an HTTP 404 error:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report
Message The requested resource [/opencms/] is not available
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
Apache Tomcat/11.0.0-M17
```

I've checked the configurations, but I'm unable to figure out why the endpoint isn't working. Could someone please guide me on how to fix this issue? Additionally, if there's a better approach to deploying OpenCms on Tomcat via Puppet on AWS, I'm open to suggestions. Thanks in advance!

I tried using these urls:

https://quicknotepadtutorial.blogspot.com/2020/10/how-to-install-opencms-with-nginx.html

[https://www.jahia.com/home/blog/pagecontent/blogs-list/java-based-cms-built-on-apache-tomcat.html#:~:text=There%20are%20several%20ways%20you,or%20uploading%20a%20WAR%20file](https://www.jahia.com/home/blog/pagecontent/blogs-list/java-based-cms-built-on-apache-tomcat.html#:%7E:text=There%20are%20several%20ways%20you,or%20uploading%20a%20WAR%20file).